# Android File Transfer over USB

Tags: java, android

How can I make copy files from Android phone over USB connection using Java?

Comment: What kind of file transfer are you looking to do? Do you want to transfer files from inside an Android app directly into a folder on the connected PC?  Or do you want to transfer data to the device's sdcard from an Android app, and then, run an app on the host pc to retrieve the sdcard?  etc..

Comment: I want to get something like a window explorer for the files on my android sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'adb pull" command or TCP, adb pull also bases TCP.
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb pull ...");

try this please.

Comment: Note that this will only work from Java code **running on the PC** - it **will not** work from Android *application* Java code.